# Upload a file to a web page as an attachment using VBA

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, vba

I have a situation here. My company has a webpage which we use for ticket creation. The user gets the email and he has to create a ticket based on the info in the email. I tried to automate this process however got stuck at uploading the attachment.

When the user click on the attach button, a new pop up opens and my macro looses the control over the pop up.

So currently what am doing is,
Save the email - which needs to be attached.
Copy the path to clip board using a function
run a vb script to paste and enter using send keys with 5 seconds delay
click on the attach button.

So before the macro clicks the attach button, a VBS runs behind to paste and hit enter. So by the time the pop up opens VBS starts and closes the pop up.

I was checking to run the attach function within VB script so that I dont have to click on attach button. But I am not able to reach anywhere. anyone help?

The below are the functions available in the webpage. I dont know which one to run and how.

```js
<script eval="true">/**
 * Validate the attachments to see if at least
 * one file is attached. Otherwise, show an alert.
 *
 * @returns {Boolean}
 */
function validateAttachment() {
var form = $('sys_attachment');
var fileFields = form.select('.attachmentRow');
for (var i = 0; i &lt; fileFields.size(); i++) {
if (fileFields[i] && fileFields[i].value != "") {
setAttachButton(""); //disable
$('please_wait').style.display = "";
return true;
}
}
alert("Choose a file to attach");
    return false;
}
/**
 * Does the first attachment input field have a value?
 * If not, use the grey button and change type of cursor.
 * @param value
 */
function setDeleteButton(value) {
var field = $$('.attachmentRow')[0];
var text = field.select('input')[0];
var deleteButton = field.select('a.attachfile-delete img')[0];
if (!text.getValue().empty()) {
deleteButton.setAttribute('src', 'images/icons/kb_no.gif');
deleteButton.up().style.cursor = 'pointer';
} else {
deleteButton.setAttribute('src', 'images/icons/kb_no_disabled.gif');
deleteButton.up().style.cursor = 'default';
}
}
/**
 * If the value passed in is an empty string,
 * set the button to disabled state, otherwise
 * enabled.
 *
 * @param value
 */
function setAttachButton(value) {
  var attachButton = $("attachButton");
  if (value == "")
    attachButton.disabled = "true";
  else
    attachButton.disabled = "";
}
/**
 * This controls the remove button for all attachments.
 * If there are attachments in the list enable the button.
 * Else keep disabled.
 *
 * @param e
 */
function setRemoveButton(e) {
  var removeButton = gel("removeButton");
  var deletedSysIdsElement = gel("deleted_sys_ids");
  var deletedSysIds = new Array();
  var deletedString = deletedSysIdsElement.value;
  if (deletedString)
     deletedSysIds = deletedString.split(";");
  var thisId = e.name.substring(7);
  if (e.checked) {
    removeButton.disabled = "";
    deletedSysIds.push(thisId);
  } else {
    var index = deletedSysIds.indexOf(thisId);
    deletedSysIds.splice(index, 1);
    // are there any left checked?
    var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
    var nonechecked = true;
    var i = 0;
    while(i &lt; inputs.length && nonechecked) {
      if (inputs[i].type == "checkbox" && inputs[i].name.substring(0, 7) == "sys_id_")
        if (inputs[i].checked)
          nonechecked = false;
        i++;
    }
    if (nonechecked) {
      removeButton.disabled = "true";
    }
  }
  deletedSysIds = deletedSysIds.join(";");
  deletedSysIdsElement.value = deletedSysIds;
}
function startRemoveAttachments() {
  var removeButton = gel("removeButton");
  removeButton.disabled = true;
  gel('please_wait').style.display = "";
  var thisUrl = gel("sysparm_this_url");
  thisUrl.value = "attachment_deleted.do?sysparm_domain_restore=false&sysparm_nostack=yes&sysparm_deleted=" + gel("deleted_sys_ids").value;
  return true;
}
/**
 * Clear and Remove the attachment field that is
 * passed in.
 *
 * @param field_id
 */
function clearAttachmentField(field) {
var form = $('sys_attachment');
var fileFields = form.select('.attachmentRow');
fileFields[0].setAttribute('data-position', 'first');
if (fileFields.size() &gt; 1 && (field.readAttribute('data-position') != "first")) {
//check if field you are removing has a 3rd column (does it have an attach button?)
var needToAttachButton;
        var attachButton = field.select('td')[2];
        if (attachButton)
        needToAttachButton = true;
        //remove the field
field.remove();
//if you removed a field with a third column, add an attachbutton onto the new "first" field.
if (attachButton) {
var attachButton = new Element('input', {
   "type": "submit",
   "id": "attachButton",
   "disabled": "true",
   "value": "Attach" });
var td = new Element('td', {align: 'right'}).update(attachButton);
Element.extend(td);
form.select('.attachmentRow').first().select('td')[1].insert({'after': td});
}
}
else
clearFileField(field.select('td').first().select('input').first());
checkAndSetAttachButton();
}
/**
 * Check all attachment input fields. If there is not attachment
 * currently, disable the attachment button, else enable it.
 *
 * @returns
 */
function checkAndSetAttachButton() {
var form = $('sys_attachment');
var fileFields = form.select('.attachmentRow');
        var validFileCount = 0;
for (var i = 0; i &lt; fileFields.size(); i++) {
var field = fileFields[i].select('td').first().select('input').first();
if (field.getValue() != "") {
if (window.File && window.FileReader && window.FileList)
validFileCount += validateSizeandExt(field);
else
validFileCount += 1;
}
        }
        if (validFileCount == 0)
        setAttachButton("");
        else
setAttachButton("true");
}
function validateSizeandExt(field) {
var form = $('sys_attachment');
var maxSize = (form.max_size && form.max_size.value) ? form.max_size.value : 0;
var fileTypes = (form.file_types && form.file_types.value) ? form.file_types.value : "";
var files = field.files;
var allowedSize = maxSize * 1048576;
    var warningString = "";
var checkJEXL = true;
for (var i = 0; i &lt; files.length; i++) {
if (checkJEXL && isJEXLExpression(files[i].name)) {
warningString += files[i].name + " is an invalid file name.\n";
}
if (files[i].size &gt; allowedSize && allowedSize != 0)
warningString += files[i].name + " is " + getDisplaySize(files[i].size) + ". The maximum file size is " + getDisplaySize(allowedSize) + ".\n";
                if (!isValidFileType(files[i], fileTypes))
                        warningString += files[i].name + " has a prohibited file extension." + "\n";
}
        if (warningString != "") {
                alert(warningString);
                clearFileField(field);
                return 0;
        }
        return 1;
}
function isJEXLExpression(fileName) {
var phaseOneOpening = fileName.indexOf("$" + "{");
var phaseTwoOpening = fileName.indexOf("$" + "[");
if (phaseOneOpening != -1 || phaseTwoOpening != -1) {
return true;
}
return false;
}
function getDisplaySize(sizeInBytes) {
var kilobytes = Math.round(sizeInBytes / 1024);
if (kilobytes &lt; 1)
kilobytes = 1;
var reportSize = kilobytes + "K";
if (kilobytes &gt; 1024)
reportSize = Math.round(kilobytes / 1024) + "MB";
return reportSize;
}
function isValidFileType(file, types) {
var extensions = types || "";
        if (extensions != "") {
extensions.toLowerCase();
extensions = extensions.split(",");
var periodIndex = file.name.lastIndexOf(".");
        var extension = file.name.substring(periodIndex+1).toLowerCase();
        if (extensions.indexOf(extension) == -1)
return false;
}
        return true;
}
/**
 * Clear a given field's contents.
 *
 * @param field
 * the field element.
 */
function clearFileField(field) {
$(field).clear();
$(field).parentNode.innerHTML = $(field).parentNode.innerHTML;
checkAndSetAttachButton();
}
/**
 * If the attachments are uploaded, clear any extra attachment input fields so
 * they do not take up as much screen space. Additionally, clear the first field
 * and keep it showing.
 */
function clearAttachmentFields() {
   var form = $('sys_attachment');
   var fileFields = form.select('.attachmentRow');
   for (var i = 0; i &lt; fileFields.size(); i++) {
   if (i == 0)
   clearFileField(fileFields[0].select('td').first().select('input').first());
   if (i &gt; 0)
   fileFields[i].remove();
   }
   checkAndSetAttachButton();
   setDeleteButton();
}
// this get called after an attachment is uploaded to update the display
function refreshAttachments(id, fileName, canDelete, createdBy, createdOn, contentType, encryption, iconPath) {
  refreshLiveFeedAttachments(id, fileName, contentType, iconPath);
  var encryptCheck = gel("encrypt_checkbox");
  if (encryptCheck) {
     encryptCheck.checked = false;
     $('sysparm_encryption_context').value = "";
  }
  gel("please_wait").style.display = "none";
  // if we didn't get an id, we could not read the attachment due to business rules so we're done
  if (typeof id == "undefined")
     return;
  var noAttachments = gel("no_attachments");
  if (noAttachments.style.display == "block")
     noAttachments.style.display = "none";
  // add the new upload to the display
  var table = gel("attachment_table_body");
  var tr = cel("tr");
  var td = cel("td");
  td.style.whiteSpace = "nowrap";
  td.colspan = "2";
  if (canDelete=="true") {
     var input = cel("input");
     var checkId = "sys_id_" + id;
     input.name = checkId;
     input.id = checkId;
     input.type = "checkbox";
     input.onclick = function() {setRemoveButton(gel(checkId));};
     td.appendChild(input);
     gel("delete_button_span").style.display = "inline";
     var text = document.createTextNode(" ");
     td.appendChild(text);
     input = cel("input");
     input.type = "hidden";
     input.name = "Name";
     input.value = "false";
     td.appendChild(input);
  }
  var attachment_input = cel("input");
  attachment_input.className = "attachment_sys_id";
  attachment_input.type = "hidden";
  attachment_input.id = id;
  td.appendChild(attachment_input);
  var anchor = cel("a");
  anchor.style.marginRight = "4px";
  anchor.href = "sys_attachment.do?sys_id=" + id;
  anchor.title = "Attached by " + createdBy + " on " + createdOn;
  var imgSrc = iconPath;
  if (encryption != "") {
     anchor.title += ", Encrypted: " + encryption;
     imgSrc = "images/icons/attachment_encrypted.gifx";
  }
  var img = cel("img");
  img.src = imgSrc;
  img.alt = anchor.title;
  anchor.appendChild(img);
  var text = $(cel('a'));
  getMessage("Download {0}", function(msg) {
  text.setAttribute("aria-label", new GwtMessage().format(msg, fileName));
  });
  text.href = "sys_attachment.do?sys_id=" + id;
  text.onkeydown = function(event){return allowInPlaceEditModification(text, event);};
  text.style.marginRight = "5px";
  text.style.maxWidth = "75%";
  text.style.display = "inline-block";
  text.style.overflow = "hidden";
  text.style.verticalAlign = "middle";
  if ('innerText' in text)
      text.innerText = fileName;
  else
      text.textContent = fileName;
  text.setAttribute("data-id", id);
  text.inPlaceEdit({
      selectOnStart: true,
      turnClickEditingOff: true,
  onBeforeEdit: function() {
  text.lastAriaLabel = text.getAttribute("aria-label");
  text.removeAttribute("aria-label");
  text.setAttribute("role", "textbox");
  },
  onEditCancelled: function() {
  text.removeAttribute("role");
  if (text.lastAriaLabel) {
  text.setAttribute("aria-label", text.lastAriaLabel);
  }
  },
      onAfterEdit: function(newName) {
          var oldName = this.oldValue;
          var ga = new GlideAjax('AttachmentAjax');
          ga.addParam('sysparm_type', 'rename');
          ga.addParam('sysparm_value', id);
          ga.addParam('sysparm_name', newName);
          ga.getXML(function(response){
             var answer = response.responseXML.documentElement.getAttribute("answer");
           if (answer !== '0')
                 alert(new GwtMessage().getMessage("Renaming attachment {0} to new name {1} is not allowed", oldName, newName));
             $$('a[data-id="' + id + '"]').each(function(elem){
                 if ('innerText' in elem)
                     elem.innerText = (answer === '0') ? newName : oldName;
                 else
                     elem.textContent = (answer === '0') ? newName : oldName;
             });
             $$('span[data-id="' + id + '"]').each(function(elem){
                 if ('innerText' in elem)
                     elem.innerText = (answer === '0') ? newName : oldName;
                 else
                     elem.textContent = (answer === '0') ? newName : oldName;
             });
  
   /*
   This routine updates the attachment in the attachment modal AND the same attachment on the parent form
   */
 getMessage(["Download {0}", "View {0}", "Rename {0}"], function(msg) {
 var newDownloadText = new GwtMessage().format(msg["Download {0}"], newName);
 var newViewText = new GwtMessage().format(msg["View {0}"], newName);
 var newRenameText = new GwtMessage().format(msg["Rename {0}"], newName);
 console.log(id)
 $$('a[data-id="' + id + '"]').each(function(elem){
 elem.setAttribute("aria-label", newDownloadText);
 })
 $$('.view_' + id).each(function(elem){
 elem.setAttribute("aria-label", newViewText);
 })
 $$('.rename_' + id).each(function(elem){
 elem.setAttribute("aria-label", newRenameText);
 })
 })
  text.removeAttribute("role");
           });
      }
  });
  if (contentType == "text/html")
     anchor.target = "_blank";
  td.appendChild(anchor);
  td.appendChild(text);
  var allowRename = gel('ni.show_rename_link').value;
  if (allowRename == "true") {
  var renameAttachment = $(cel('a'));
  renameAttachment.href = "#";
  renameAttachment.setAttribute("role", "button");
  getMessage("Rename {0}", function(msg) {
  renameAttachment.setAttribute("aria-label", new GwtMessage().format(msg, fileName));
  });
  renameAttachment.className = 'attachment rename_' + id;
  renameAttachment.onclick = function() {
    text.beginEdit();
  };
 renameAttachment.innerHTML = '[rename]';
  td.appendChild(renameAttachment);
  }
  var showView = gel("ni.show_attachment_view").value;
  if (showView == "true") {
      var blank = document.createTextNode(" ");
      tr.appendChild(blank);
      var view = cel("a");
  view.href = "#";
  getMessage("View {0}", function(msg) {
    view.setAttribute("aria-label", new GwtMessage().format(msg, fileName));
  });
      var newText = document.createTextNode('[view]');
      view.appendChild(newText);
      view.className = "attachment view_" + id;
      if (showPopup == "false")
          view.href = "sys_attachment.do?sys_id=" + id + "&view=true";
      else
          view.onclick = function() {
              tearOffAttachment(id)
          };
      td.appendChild(blank);
      td.appendChild(view);
  }
  var showPopup = gel("ni.show_attachment_popup").value;
  tr.appendChild(td);
  table.appendChild(tr);
//If a new attachment is added check if attachments are marked for edge encryption before showing the Download all button
if (!edgeEncryptionEnabledForAttachments && hasAttachments()){
  gel("download_all_button").style.display = "inline";
  }
  var form_table_id = "";
  if(gel("sys_uniqueValue") || gel("sysparm_attachment_cart_id")){
  form_table_id = (gel("sys_uniqueValue") || gel("sysparm_attachment_cart_id")).value;
  }
  if(form_table_id && attachmentParentSysId != form_table_id){
  CustomEvent.fire('record.attachment.uploaded', {
  sysid: id,
  name: fileName,
  hoverText: anchor.title,
  image: imgSrc,
  showRename: allowRename,
  showView: showView,
  showPopup: showPopup
  });
  }else{
  addAttachmentNameToForm(id, fileName, anchor.title, imgSrc, allowRename, showView, showPopup);
  }
  if (g_accessibility)
    alert(fileName + " " + anchor.title);
}
function refreshLiveFeedAttachments(sys_id, fileName, contentType, iconPath) {
var p = gel('live_feed_message_images');
if (!p)
return;
if (!contentType)
return;
    if (contentType.indexOf('image') != 0 || contentType.indexOf('image/tif') == 0)
refreshLiveFeedNonImages(p, sys_id, iconPath, fileName);
else
refreshLiveFeedImages(p, sys_id, fileName);
var container = $('live_feed_image_container');
if (container)
container.show();
}
function refreshLiveFeedNonImages(p, sys_id, iconPath, fileName) {
var a = cel('a');
    a.onclick = function() {tearOffAttachment(sys_id)};
    a.title = fileName;
    a.className = "live_feed_attachment_link";
    var img = cel('img');
    img.src = iconPath;
    img.className = 'live_feed_image_thumbnail';
img.setAttribute("data-sys_id", sys_id);
    a.appendChild(img);
var span = cel('span');
    span.setAttribute('data-id', sys_id);
if ('innerText' in span)
span.innerText = fileName;
else
span.textContet = fileName;
a.appendChild(span);
    p.appendChild(a);
p.appendChild(cel('br'));
    setTimeout(this.hideLoading.bind(this), 200);
}
function refreshLiveFeedImages(p, sys_id, fileName) {
var imageName = "sys_attachment.do?sys_id=" + sys_id;
var a = cel('a');
    a.onclick = function() {tearOffAttachment(sys_id)};
    a.title = fileName;
    a.className = "live_feed_attachment_link";
    var img = cel('img');
    img.src = imageName;
    img.className = 'live_feed_image_thumbnail';
img.setAttribute("data-sys_id", sys_id);
    a.appendChild(img);
    p.appendChild(a);
p.appendChild(cel('br'));
    setTimeout(this.hideLoading.bind(this), 200);
}
// this get called after attachments are deleted to update the display
function deletedAttachments(sysIds) {
var form_table_id = "";
if(gel("sys_uniqueValue") || gel("sysparm_attachment_cart_id")){
form_table_id = (gel("sys_uniqueValue") || gel("sysparm_attachment_cart_id")).value;
}
if(form_table_id && attachmentParentSysId != form_table_id){
CustomEvent.fire('record.attachment.deleted', sysIds);
return;
}
deleteLiveFeedAttachments(sysIds);
var modified = $("attachments_modified");
if (modified)
modified.value = "true";
   var header_attachment = $('header_attachment');
   gel("deleted_sys_ids").value = ""; // there should be none on the list once we return
   var idArray = sysIds.split(";");
   for (var i=0; i&lt;idArray.length; i++) {
      var id = idArray[i];
      changeCount(attachmentParentSysId, 'decrease');
      var e = gel("sys_id_" + id);
      var tr = e.parentNode.parentNode;
      rel(tr);
      e = gel("attachment_" + id);
      if (e)
         rel(e);
   }
   var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
   var anAttachment = false;
   var i = 0;
   while(i &lt; inputs.length && !anAttachment) {
      if (inputs[i].type == "checkbox" && inputs[i].name.substring(0, 7) == "sys_id_")
         anAttachment = true;
      i++;
   }
   if (!anAttachment) {
      var noAttachments = gel("no_attachments");
      noAttachments.style.display = "none";
      var removeButton = gel("removeButton");
      removeButton.disabled = true;
  var downloadAllButton = gel("download_all_button");
  downloadAllButton.style.display = "none";
  gel('delete_button_span').style.display = "none";
  hideObject($("header_attachment_list_label"));
      if (header_attachment)
      header_attachment.style.height = "auto";
      var line = $("header_attachment_line");
      if (line) {
         line.style.visibility = "hidden";
         line.style.display = "none";
      }
   }
   gel("please_wait").style.display = "none";
   var more_attachments = $('more_attachments');
   if (more_attachments && header_attachment)
   if( (computeAttachmentWidth() - 20) &gt;= (header_attachment.getWidth() - more_attachments.getWidth()))
       more_attachments.style.display = 'block';
   else
       more_attachments.style.display = 'none';
}
function deleteLiveFeedAttachments(sysIds) {
var p = $('live_feed_message_images');
if (!p)
return;
if (!p.visible())
return;
idArray = sysIds.split(";");
for (var i=0; i&lt;idArray.length; i++) {
var imgs = p.select("img.live_feed_image_thumbnail");
if (imgs.length &lt; 1)
return;
for (var j=0; j&lt;imgs.length; j++) {
if (imgs[j].getAttribute("data-sys_id") == idArray[i]) {
var elem = imgs[j].up("a.live_feed_attachment_link");
elem.remove();
if (elem.next() && (elem.next().tagName.toLowerCase() == "br"))
elem.next().remove();
}
}
}
if (p.select("img.live_feed_image_thumbnail").length &gt; 0)
return;
var container = $('live_feed_image_container');
if (container)
container.hide();
}
function computeAttachmentWidth() {
var temp = $('header_attachment_list').select('li');
var totalWidth = 0;
for (var i = 0; i &lt; temp.length; i++) {
totalWidth += temp[i].getWidth();
}
return totalWidth;
}
function closeAttachmentWindow() {
  GlideModal.prototype.get('attachment').destroy();
}
/**
 * Add an input field to the file browser in the dialog.
 * This is called when the "Add Another Attachment" button
 * is clicked.
 * */
function addRowToTable() {
   var formRows = $('sys_attachment').select(".attachmentRow");
   var input = "&lt;input type='file' title='Attach' " +
"name='attachFile' onchange='checkAndSetAttachButton(); setDeleteButton(this.value);'" +
"size=41 multiple=true /&gt;";
   var img = "&lt;a href='#' onclick='clearAttachmentField($(this).up().up()); setDeleteButton(this.value);'&gt;" +
"&lt;img src='images/icons/kb_no.gif'/&gt;&lt;/a&gt;";
var row = "&lt;tr class='attachmentRow'&gt;&lt;td&gt; "
+ input + "&lt;/td&gt;&lt;td align='right'&gt;" + img + "&lt;/td&gt;&lt;/tr&gt;";
formRows.last().insert({ "after" : row });
}
/**
 * Download all attachments
 */
function downloadAllAttachments(){
var downloadUrl = window.location.protocol + '//' + window.location.host + '/download_all_attachments.do?sysparm_sys_id=' + attachmentParentSysId;
window.location = downloadUrl;
}
function hasAttachments(){
return document.getElementsByClassName("attachment_sys_id").length &gt; 0;
}</script>
```

This is what happens when I click on the attach button in the HTML. attachFile is the ID which I am using in my code to run.

```html
<tr class="attachmentRow">
<td id="attachFileCell" colspan="3">
<input name="attachFile" title="" id="attachFile" onchange="checkAndSetAttachButton(); setDeleteButton(this.value); $('attachButton').click();" type="file" size="41" multiple="true" data-original-title="Attach">
<a class="attachfile-delete" style="display: none; cursor: default;" onclick="clearAttachmentField($(this).up().up()); setDeleteButton(this.value);" href="#">
<img src="images/icons/kb_no_disabled.gif">
</a>
<input disabled="" class="attachfile-attach button" id="attachButton" style="display: none;" type="submit" value="Attach">
</td>
</tr>
```

This is my VBA Code which I used.

```html
Set IE = New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
            IE.Visible = True
            
            IE.Navigate "https://sorry cant share the link as per the company policy"
            Do While IE.Busy = True Or IE.READYSTATE <> 4: DoEvents: Loop
        
            Set HTMLDoc = IE.Document
            
    '***************** Save Email

            eachitem.SaveAs StrFile, 3
            
    '***************** file link to clipboard
            CopyText StrFile
                    
    '***************** Attach Email
            HTMLDoc.getElementById("header_add_attachment").Click
            Application.Wait (Now() + TimeValue("00:00:02"))
            
    '***************** Call external VBS file to handle the pop up then attach
            Shell "Explorer.exe " & StrFolderPath & "SNOW.vbs", vbNormalFocus
            HTMLDoc.getElementById("attachFile").Click
            SendKeys "{Enter}", True
```

I tried the below method to call the function, but reaching nowhere! Any assistance would be appreciated. I really dont know which function attaches the file to the website and how.

```html
Set HTMLDoc1 = IE.Document.parentWindow
        HTMLDoc1.execScript code:="isJEXLExpression(" & StrFile & ")"
        HTMLDoc1.execScript code:="checkAndSetAttachButton()"
        HTMLDoc1.execScript code:="setDeleteButton(this.value)"
        HTMLDoc1.execScript code:="$('attachButton').click()"
        HTMLDoc1.execScript code:="clearAttachmentField($(this).up().up()); setDeleteButton(this.value);"
```

Comment: You are trying to call you own custom function is that right?

Comment: What creates these emails? The reason I ask is that if you can create the tickets from the same source data that created the email, you won't need all of these workarounds.

Comment: These emails are sent by multiple senders and we read it from outlook and create tickets

Comment: @qharr no, am trying call the function in web page to upload the attachment

Comment: Did you try HTMLDoc1.querySelector("#attachFile").FireEvent "onchange"  though I am not hopeful about that.

Comment: @QHarr - Unfortunately I tried that and i get the error "Object doesnt support this property or method"